# Por que o seletor universal * causa impacto negativo na renderização dos browsers?

Tags: css, navegador-de-internet, desempenho

Estava fui aplicar um CSS Reset em meu site.
Geralmente uso o sugerido pelo Eric Meyer http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ .
Mas tava olhando a sugestão do Diego Eis em http://tableless.com.br/css-reset/ que é assim :

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

Achei bacana, mais simples (logicamente a do Eric Meyer é mais completo.)

Fui testar no meu Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web, e o Web Essentials disparou um aviso dizendo :

> Performance : Never use the universal selector. It has a big negative
>   performance impact on browsers rendering.

Traduzindo :

> Performance : Nunca use o seletor universal. Isso tem um grande
>   impacto negativo em performance na renderização do browser.

Por que o seletor universal `*` causa esse impacto negativo na renderização dos browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O conceito de que o seletor universal é lento é um mito cunhado dez anos atrás quando, de fato, haviam problemas de performance, nada surpreendentemente, por causa do Internet Explorer 6.

Hoje em dia, em browsers modernos o impacto de performance do seletor universal é insignificante contanto que você não defina regras que resultem em efeitos mais lentos nele.

Diferentemente do artigo de referência, pessoalmente, eu não definiria efeitos CSS3 no seletor universal. Não apenas porque eu veementemente duvido que TODOS os elementos REALMENTE precisariam daquele efeito em particular, mas também porque sou a favor de classes genéricas reutilizáveis presente em *frameworks* CSS como o Bootstrap.

Fonte: [Artigo](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-09-28/css_tip_star_selector_not_that_bad) no Blog do Telerik através de [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13432169) no SOen

Answer (score 2):

O principal argumento contra o seletor universal nem era tanto a performance, mas o impacto que ele causava na herança de propriedades.

Na prática, nem perda de desempenho e nem problemas de herança jamais foram relevantes o suficiente para abolir o uso, até porque era muito mais rápido e prático utilizá-lo e fazer algumas poucas definições específicas em seguida, inclusive adotando folhas de estilos específicas para o finado IE6, que já era obsoleto quando o uso do CSS2 ganhou força e os layouts baseados em tabelas começaram a entrar em desuso.

Um modelo que eu sempre adotei, recentemente atualizado para o html5, foi:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 /* outros estilos com base no projeto */ 
}

div, article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { 
  text-decoration:none; 
  font:inherit; 
}

li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

Até porque, novamente, na prática, você precisa sempre definir os estilos de acordo com o projeto, cada um especificamente, e no reset entram apenas os elementos que realmente podem atrapalhar ou se repetem muito na criação.

Comment: Sei não, hein. Quando o CSS3 deu as caras, tinha um site, não lembro qual, que fazia um tipo de benchmark do navegador para ver quais efeitos este suportava e com que velocidade eles eram processados. Daí é lógica: se um efeito é pesado demais para um seletor, se aplicado ao universal a coisa fica feia.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, o último teste que vi foi de 2009, e não acredito que a coisa tenha piorado. Na época o impacto foi considerado insignificante para todos os principais navegadores, principalmente levando em consideração o aspecto custo de desenvolvimento, sugerindo mais atenção com a aplicação de certas regras particularmente pesadas (não o seletor) e suas interações com o javascript. Junto com o CSS3, também houve muita evolução na tecnologia dos navegadores. Em tempo, acabei de encontrar esse link de 2012: http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-09-28/css_tip_star_selector_not_that_bad

Comment: Alguma coisa mais antiga que isso? O artigo original que eu usei na tradução menciona 10 anos. Como será que era a coisa em 2004 ou antes?

Comment: Até 2004, precisamente, quando começou a vingar a ideia de web standards, boas práticas, tableless, flash é coisa do mal, etc... Ninguém ligava para isso. Layout era com tabelas, imagens fatiadas, e ponto final. Site bom tinha que ter flash com no mínimo 10MB (no tempo em que o download médio era de 256kbits/segundo) e animações para tudo quanto é lado. O máximo que se usava do CSS era para mudar a cor do link ou esconder quilômetros de palavras-chave para o Google encontrar.

Comment: Bastante interessante :)